# How to prevent snow steps from Snow Golems?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a mod or a command that will stop snow golems from leaving snow on the floor? I made a wonderful home and it's being tarnished by the appearance of the snow!

Comment: light sources (like torches and glowstone) prevent snow.. you would need a lot though to cover the flooring.. thats why this isn't an answer. just an idea

Comment: Do torches still melt snow?  You could put some in your house and the snow should go away after a short time.

Comment: Is there a surface that snow doesn't collect on? You could use that as your flooring.

Comment: @ChargingPun There's carpet but I don't want my entire house carpeted.

Comment: Does snow gather on slabs in the bottom half of a block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some in-game testing, I have found that Snow Golems do not leave a trail on transparent blocks, including slabs. So you could replace your floor with upside-down slabs to keep the trails off. Adding a carpet will also keep the trails away.

Alternatively, you could light up the floor, but this may not be as practical, since that would require that you place torches on the floor every 2 or 3 blocks. So in this case, your best bet is to go with some transparent block for the floor.

Note: As of Minecraft 1.9 snapshot 15w46a Snow Golems will now no longer leave a trail of snow if the GameRule doMobGriefing is set to false.

Comment: Could you put glowstone under the flooring?